# Display the Connection ID of mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I want to add a sniplet of code where I can print the connection id of the connection made to mysql using `getConnection()`.
It is going to be used for monitoring the number of connections made at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection is an interface and is implemented by multiple database vendors. I am entirely sure whether you can get such a value, but it depends whether MySQL is actually allowing you to do or not.

Regarding you problem of monitoring the number of connections made at a time, based on your requirement you can actually go for a synchronized counter to maintain the number of times the connection made/closed/open. Hope that helps.

Comment: SELECT CONNECTION_ID(); this query gives me the id, I want to know if there is a way to print it into a java code without query firing stmt. synchronized counter won't help as we have a few threads which sleep and the id will help us to pin point which thread is in sleep mode

Comment: Connection is just a bridge, you are fetching the CONNECTION_ID from the DB and not from the Connection Object. I dont think there is any, but I will try for anything that might help you.